# SASS, What is the correct way to call a mixin?

Tags: sass

I just started using SASS and  I am trying to figure out how to create a box shadow mixin...

**I copied this mixin from another stack overflow post..**

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {

      -webkit-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
      -moz-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
      box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
    }
```

However I am not sure exactly how to format my `@include`

**This is what I have so far for my @include**

```
@include box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
```

**And this is my output error...**

```
error(Line 1003: Invalid CSS after "...lude box-shadow": expected "}", was ": inset 0 1px 1...")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bad syntax.

Use `@include box-shadow(0, 1px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), inset);`

(Edited in 2014 to include changes to Sass' syntax made in the last few years)

Comment: Tried this example and it does not seem to be working plus the options are out of order when listed.

Answer (score 9):

I'm new to Sass and the accepted answer didn't work to me; the order of the values looks wrong and the values also require commas after each one. I used the following:

```
@include box-shadow(0, 1px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), inset);
```

Comment: This will only let you use only one shadow. The accepted answer allows multiple.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you are describing? If you use the provided syntax given in the accepted answer with the mixin in the question I receive an error:
Mixin box-shadow is missing argument $left.

Comment: Use this with the accepted answer because of syntax error `forgot the commas`

Answer (score 4):

I think you should include some defaults:

```
@mixin box-shadow($left:0, $top:2px, $blur:2px, $color:#000, $inset:"") {
      -webkit-box-shadow:$left $top $blur $color #{$inset};
      -moz-box-shadow:$left $top $blur $color #{$inset};
      box-shadow:$left $top $blur $color #{$inset};
}
```

That way, you don't need to set your options every time if you want to use the same code:

```
.your-selector {
    @include box-shadow();
}
```

I have also corrected the order of the options: horizontal normally appears before vertical.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016, looks like things have changed again from the accepted answers. Referecing Compass documentation and [examples here](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_shadow/), the following will work in a SCSS file:

`@include box-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)0 0 3px 1px inset);`

That shadow is very faint, so I actually used:

`@include box-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)0 0 3px 1px inset);`

**For multiple shadows:**
Separate each shadow with a comma.

`@include box-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)0 0 3px 1px inset, rgba(blue, 0.4) 0 0 5px 5px);`

Comment: No one is asking about Compass.  The question is specifically asking about a syntax error while attempting to use a mixin the OP wrote.

Answer (score -1):

For 'Silverback' an example would be:

```
@include box-shadow(inset 0, 1px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075));
```

It includes the forgotten commas that 'pixel 67' commented.

Comment: I suppose technically you can use this but I think that if you were to follow the given mixin variable order you would have to put the "inset" at the end (not saying it syntactically belongs there); it looks like you can enter whatever you want in the 4 spots and it will spit it out regardless:
`@include box-shadow(dog, cat, frog, gnat);`

But you're right, it's the commas that are making it work.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'm fresh to SASS as well and actually followed your example. Another way to achieve this without dealing with commas is passing a different argument.


`@mixin box-shadow($shadow...) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadow;
  box-shadow: $shadow;
}`


`@include box-shadow(0 0 20px rgba($black,0.8));`
-OR-
`@include box-shadow(0px 1px 4px rgba($black, 0.3), 0px 0px 40px rgba($black, 0.1) inset);`

In the end just like anything else a ton of ways to do the same thing.