# What is wrong with my box-shadow SASS @Mixin?

Tags: sass, mixins, css

I am trying to find a working box-shadow @mixin for SASS.

**My CodePen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/nCDos**

On stackoverflow I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435056/creating-a-box-shadow-mixin-using-sass) and used it and the answer exactly, however I'm still getting the following error:

[image]

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
    -webkit-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
    -moz-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
    box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
}

.login_window {
    width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red;

    @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

How would you write it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add commas between each component value:

```
.login_window {
    width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red;
    @include box-shadow(inset 0, 1px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrIuh

Comment: Ah thanks! :D with the quickness, another 10 mins before I can check

Comment: This will not work with all formats of the box-shadow.  Take a look here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow

Answer (score 16):

For a simple prefix mixin, especially when the property has optional values, it would be better to not have specific arguments.  In the case of box-shadow, *blur* and *offset* are both optional (note that your mixin only accounts for blur, not offset).

```
@mixin box-shadow($value) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $value;
    -moz-box-shadow: $value;
    box-shadow: $value;
}

.foo {
    @include box-shadow(0 0 .25em .25em black);
}

.bar {
    @include box-shadow(inset 1px 1px 1px blue);
}
```

This way, you've already practiced the correct order for the values and you don't have to relearn them when your prefix mixin is no longer needed.  Also, you won't have all of those commas to remove.  Note that this is how [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) has all of its prefix mixins written.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add another argument for more flexibility - the spread (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp):

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $spread, $color, $inset: false) {
  @if $inset {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color inset;
    box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color inset;
  } @else {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color;
    -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color;
    box-shadow: $top $left $blur $spread $color;
  }
}
```

Now you have a mixin that really can generate all kinds of box-shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use the `...` operator. Because, format of the box-shadow and the number of arguments can be different in different situations.

You can read all about it here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow

### This code will work no matter what your format is

```
// mixins
@mixin box-shadow($shadow...) {
    box-shadow: $shadow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: $shadow;
    -moz-box-shadow: $shadow;
    -ms-box-shadow: $shadow;
    -o-box-shadow: $shadow;
}

.your-class-here {
  @include box-shadow(5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6));
}
```